# Missing and inaccurate payload in Rails with ActiveModel and Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activemodel

I have a model for `Organisation` like

```
class Organisation
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :orguid,
                :title, :firstname, :lastname, :role, :telephone, :extension, :email,
                :name, :branch, :address1, :address2, :address3, :city, :state, :country, :zip

end
```

In my controller I have the following actions:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'cgi'
require 'json'

class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
  include Secured

  before_action :set_api, only: %i[dashboard create]
  before_action :user_info, only: %i[dashboard register]

  def dashboard
    @registration = @api.registered?
  end

  def register
    @organisation = Organisation.new
  end

  def create
    organisation_params
    register_data = params[:organisation].to_h
    register_data['oruid'] = org_uid
    @api.register(register_data)
  end

  private

  def set_api
    @api = CoreApi.new(org_uid)
  end

  def user_info
    @user_info = session[:userinfo].to_h
  end

  def org_uid
    CGI.escape(user_info['uid'])
  end

  def organisation_params
    params.require(:organisation).permit!
  end

end
```

in my `register.html.erb` I have:

```
<h1> Register Your Organisation</h1>


<%= form_with model: @organisation, url: org_register_path do |f| %>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Your Details</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <%= f.label :first_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <%= f.label :last_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :role %>
        <%= f.text_field :role, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <%= f.label :telephone %>
        <%= f.telephone_field :telephone, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <%= f.label :extension %>
        <%= f.text_field :extension, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', readonly:'', value: @user_info['info']['name'] %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Organisation Details</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%= f.label :branch %>
        <%= f.text_field :branch, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :address_line_1 %>
        <%= f.text_field :address1, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :address_line_2 %>
        <%= f.text_field :address2, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.label :address_line_3 %>
        <%= f.text_field :address3, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <%= f.label :zip %>
        <%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <%= f.button :Register, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and finally the `register` method in my `core_api.rb` is this:

```
  def register(data)
    body = data.to_json
    puts ">> >> >> >> #{body.class} :: #{body}"
    options = { headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, body: body }
    response = self.class.post('/organisations', options)
    #puts ">>>>>>>>>>>> #{response}"
  end
```

and finally my `routes.rb` file contains:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/' => 'home#show'

  get '/auth/auth0/callback' => 'auth0#callback'
  get '/auth/failure' => 'auth0#failure'

  get '/logout',                    to: 'logout#logout',                as: 'logout'

  get '/organisations/dashboard',   to: 'organisations#dashboard',      as: 'org_dashboard'
  get '/organisations/register',    to: 'organisations#register',       as: 'org_register'
  post '/organisations/register',   to: 'organisations#create'

  root 'home#show'
end
```

now when I run the server and submit the form in the logs I get:

```
>> >> >> >> String :: {"title":"","firstname":"","lastname":"","role":"","telephone":"","extension":"","email":"alijy3@yahoo.com","name":"we","branch":"we","address1":"we","address2":"","address3":"","city":"we","state":"","country":"we","zip":"","oruid":"auth0%7C5e5388493d670c11be833bca","contact_id":0}
```

which to me looks like a proper `json`. But, since the api response was continually unsuccessful I intercepted the outgoing post with *Postman* to see what payload is being sent. To my surprise the payload is not flat json, but comes out like this:
[image: Postman screenshot]

I have 2 problems with this:

- The api accepts items like `address1`, `address2`, `city`, etc. I believe I should send those rather than the currently showing `organisation[address1]`, `organisation[address2]`, etc.
- The second problem is that I add the orguid after the form is submitted and before calling/posting to the api. But, although I can see it in the log messages, I don't see the orguid in the postman payload in any form.

I don't have any database on the server. Everything is fetch/posted/saved through the api. I've been reading about how to work with Activemodel and forms for a while and I haven't managed to get this resolved yet. Any help or explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No offense but this is a train wreck. You don't need to break every rails convention just because you're not using ActiveRecord in this specific case.

Start off by using `ActiveModel::Attributes#attribute` instead of Ruby's built in `attr_accessor`.

```
class Organisation
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  [:orguid, :title, :firstname, :lastname, :role, :telephone, 
   :extension, :email, :name, :branch, 
   :address1, :address2, :address3, :city, :state, :country, :zip]
  .each do |name|
     attribute name
  end

  # @todo write validations!
end
```

This creates attributes that act like ActiveRecord attributes and you can serialize the model properly with `@organization.as_json`.

Then lets just start fresh on that controller as there is just too much smell for it to be worth salvaging.

```
# routes.rb
resources :organisations, only: [:new, :create]


class OganizationsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /organizations/new
  def new
     @organization = Organization.new
  end

  # POST /organizations
  def create
    # You never manually parse out incoming params - thats Rack's job.
    # also since you have a model - USE IT!
    @organization = Organization.new(organization_params) do |o|
      o.orguid = org_uid
    end
    # validate the user input before you send it to an external API
    if @organization.valid? && @api.register(@organization)
      redirect_to '/somewhere'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  # use monads here instead of callbacks!
  def user_info
    # Rails will serialize/deserialize hashes automatically 
    # from the session
    session[:userinfo] 
  end

  def org_uid
    # Have no clue what the heck you're doing with CGI escape. 
    @org_uid ||= user_info['uid']
  end 

  def api
    @api ||= CoreApi.new(org_uid)
  end

  def organization_params
    # You don't have any reason to use 'permit!' and give 
    # yourself a potential mass assignment vunerablity
    params.require(:organization)
          .permit(
             :title, :firstname, :lastname, :role, :telephone, 
             :extension, :email, :name, :branch, 
             :address1, :address2, :address3, :city, 
             :state, :country, :zip
           )
  end
end
```

Rename the view `/organizations/new.html.rb`. At this point you should be able to stub out the API and do an integration test with valid and invalid input.

That whole `session[:userinfo]` thing still smells really bad - if you are taking the response from OAuth and shoving it into the session your setting yourself up for a really bad time as that can cause cookie overflows. Also in general in Rails if you're ever manually casting/serializing then its a really good sign that your doing something very wrong.

Have no clue really whats going on in your CoreApi class but if you are using HTTParty you should not do ANY manual JSON encoding.

```
# @fixme name is way to generic. 
class CoreApi
  include HTTParty
  format :json # sets content type and encodes the content
  # ...
  def register(organization)
    response = self.class.post('/organisations', @organization.as_json)
    if response.success?
      true
    else
      @organization.errors.add(:base, 'Could not be registered')
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: _use monads instead of callbacks!_?

Comment: Yes @SebastianPalma. I'm not saying always use monads instead of callbacks but in this case the use of callbacks just obscures the flow. Usually when using callbacks you're DRYing the code or prefacing it with something the will raise and bail early - if your using a callback just to set an ivar thats used once then you're misusing it.

Comment: Also if you use a monad you can just right click on the method name and jump to the definition on github / in your editor instead of having to look at the top of the class to figure out where @api comes from. And you don't have to deal with figuring out when and when not the callback should run. Callbacks are good - except when they aren't.